# Change directory in current terminal with terminal file manager

Tags: bash, filemanager

Expectation:

1. open `lf` or `nnn`;
2. navigate to a desired location there;
3. `:q`
4. `$PWD` is the desired location.

Reality:

The state of the parent terminal is unchanged, directory change is local to the file manager.

Question:

Am I missing something?
Is there any way to break free from `ls;cd;ls;cd;ls;cd;ls;cd;...` curse?
Preferably without `mc` or any two-pane file managers.
I only need a lightweight visual aid for navigation, nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be something documented in source code repositories rather than in help/man pages.

There are seem to be workarounds for each file manager:

- `lf` - [repo](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf), [instruction](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf/wiki/Tutorial#working-directory);
- `nnn` - [repo](https://github.com/jarun/nnn), [instruction](https://github.com/jarun/nnn/wiki/Basic-use-cases#configure-cd-on-quit);
- `ranger` - [repo](https://github.com/ranger/ranger), [instruction](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Integration-with-other-programs#changing-directories).

In short, every file manager has some way to export the last folder path into a temporary file and there are example scripts in the repositories to help you wrap it into a shell command that will run the file manager and use the temporary file afterwards to perform the `cd` automatically.

I went with `lf`, copying `lfcd.sh` from [repo folder](https://github.com/gokcehan/lf/tree/master/etc) and sourcing it into my `~/.bashrc`. Now I can use `lfcd` when I need to quickly navigate somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the perfect solution but the `tree` command might help you with this.

Comment: Well, at least it's something, I guess. `tree -f --prune -P 'filename'` does seem to work reasonably in case I know the name of the file in the destination dir. Otherwise it doesn't really want to filter the large tree of folders.